# Can anyone identify what this set is from please? Green terrain base with large grey and black mountain pieces

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, clone-brands

Can anyone identify what this set is from?

[image]

Comment: Welcome Steve! Are you sure this is LEGO? Is "LEGO" printed anywhere on these plates (especially on the studs on top)?

Answer (score 8):

A little bit of searching identifies baseplates as being from [Mega Bloks Dragons](http://www.graysage.com/cg/Toys/Megabloks/Dragons/). The line isn't well-documented, however, so I couldn't tell exactly what set these pieces came from, or if they are indeed only from one set.

[Phil B]: Added image from the above website for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those base plates actually seem to be from a Power Ranger set:

https://bricker.info/osets/MEGABLOKS/5730/

[image: Power rangers set]